# Mongoose startSession() hangs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to connect to my Mongodb Atlas cluster through my nodejs server.

There is a certain operation which is done as a transaction. Mongoose needs `mongoose.startSession()` to be called to start a transaction. Very infrequently, this `mongoose.startSession()` call hangs indefinitely. There is no certain way to reproduce this.

```
log.info('starting lock session');
const mongoSession = await mongoose.startSession();
log.info('lock session started');
```

In above code, `starting lock session.` gets logged, but `lock session started` doesn't get logged when issue occurs.

I connect to the db like below:

```
const dburl = 'mongodb+srv://myuser:mypassword@myapp.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser: true}, err => {
    if (err) {
        log.warn('Error occurred when connecting to database. ' + err);
    }
});
```

What could be the reason for this? Could this be due to something wrong with the database? Is there any way I can further troubleshoot this?

Comment: Sessions are not started from the `mongoose` object but from the `connection` which is returned from `mongoose.connect()`. See the code in the linked answer for a correct usage example.

Comment: @NeilLunn any idea why it works most of the time?

Comment: It's really not the correct thing to do. You also might look into whether you are actually connecting to a replica set or not and the connection string used. Basically any connection string **not** using the `replicaSet` option or the `mongodb+srv` syntax where the information is in DNS can *possibly* end up connecting to a non-primary in which that would fail, or hang. I also just noted I did not included those options in the linked answer code, so I will be amending that.

Comment: @NeilLunn the documentation page says this: `Calling mongoose.startSession() is equivalent to calling mongoose.connection.startSession()`. Check: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-startSession

Comment: @NeilLunn I connect to the db with a url which looks like following: `mongodb+srv://myuser:mypassword@myapp.mongodb.net/mydb?retryWrites=true&w=majority`. I updated the question with details.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a bug in mongoose, and I reported it to mongoose but still didn't get a response.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8325

I wrote following function which I can use to wait until the mongoose connection is ready before calling `startSession()`, and it fixes my problem.

```
function waitForMongooseConnection(mongoose) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const connection = mongoose.connection;
        if (connection.readyState === 1) {
            resolve();
            return;
        }
        console.log('Mongoose connection is not ready. Waiting for open or reconnect event.');
        let resolved = false;
        const setResolved = () => {
            console.log('Mongoose connection became ready. promise already resolved: ' + resolved);
            if (!resolved) {
                console.log('Resolving waitForMongooseConnection');
                resolved = true;
                resolve();
            }
        };
        connection.once('open', setResolved);
        connection.once('reconnect', setResolved);
    });
}
```

With above function, I can start session like below:

```
log.info('starting session');
await waitForMongooseConnection(mongoose);
const mongoSession = await mongoose.startSession();
log.info('session started');
```

Note that I had to turn off `useUnifiedTopology`. Otherwise, 'reconnect' didn't get called.

```
mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: false}, err => {
    if (err) {
        log.warn('Error occurred when connecting to database. ' + err);
    }
});
```

Comment: I might come here again and for other people who wanted to refer, It only worked for me when I removed ```useunifiedTopology:true```. I didn't add the code you mentioned. Thanks anyways for the tip @Lahiru.

Answer (score 0):

> I resolved this issue by using **connection** object coming from
> `mongoose.createConnection(uri, options)`

```
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(uri, options);
const session = await connection.startSession();
session.startTransaction();
await MySchema.create({
    value: "Created?",
    session: session, // giving session here
});
await session.commitTransaction();
session.endSession();
```

> `mongoose.connection` is **different** than this connection object.

Comment: creating a new db connection whenever a request arrives on your server is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I was creating a session, it used to hang but later on I did the following and I was able to successfully create a mongodb transaction:

The example is, transfer some amount from one account to another:

Create my Account Schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {appMongoConnection} = require('../drivers/mongo/mongo.init')

const accountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

// modelname, schema, collectionname
module.exports = appMongoConnection.model('Account', accountSchema, 'accounts');
```

Let's initialize the mongodb connection:

```js
const moongoose = require('mongoose')


function setupMongoose() {
    const uri = process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URI;
    const options = {};
    const conn = moongoose.createConnection(uri, options);

    conn.on('connected', function () {
        console.info(`${conn.name} default connection is open`);
    });
    conn.on('disconnected', function () {
        console.info(`${conn.name} default connection is disconnected`);
    });

    return conn
}

const appMongoConnection = setupMongoose();

module.exports = {
    appMongoConnection
};
```

Now my router looks like:

```js
const Account = require('../models/account.model')
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {appMongoConnection} = require('../drivers/mongo/mongo.init')


const router = express.Router();

router.post('/transfer', async function handle(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Request hit 2");
    let mongoClient = appMongoConnection.getClient();
    
    const session = await mongoClient.startSession();
    const txnOptions = {
        readPreference: "primary",
        readConcern: { level: "local" },
        writeConcern: { w: "majority" }
    };

    try {
        // Since, we have written our code inside this block, if update fails, we need not
        // explicitly call await session.abortTransaction(); to rollback transaction
        await session.withTransaction(async () => {
            const opts = { session };
            let { from, to, amount } = req.body;

            const sender = await Account.findById(from).session(session);
            if (!sender) throw new Error('Sender account not found');

            const receiver = await Account.findById(to).session(session);
            if (!receiver) throw new Error('Receiver account not found');

            sender.amount -= amount;
            receiver.amount += amount;

            await sender.save(opts);

            // if (sender !== null) {
            //     throw new Error("Intentionally raising exception");
            // }

            await receiver.save(opts);

            // Commit transaction
            await session.commitTransaction();

            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Transaction successful' });
        }, txnOptions);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Transaction error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Transaction failed' });
    } finally {
        await session.endSession();
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Done